# Getting the exception message or complete exception in MSTest using reflection

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, mstest

I have few selenium tests and there are exception handling mechanisms for the most expected exceptions like ElementNotFoundException, ElementNotVisibleException in my global exception handling block. In the below block using the WebDriverWait I was able to handle the known exceptions but sometimes in my webpage there are chances of getting ElementNotInteractble exception and some other unhandled exceptions.

```cs
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds ((Constants.MediumWaitTime)));

wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(
    typeof(WebDriverTimeoutException),
    typeof(NoSuchElementException),
    typeof(ElementNotVisibleException),
    typeof(StaleElementReferenceException),
    typeof(ElementClickInterceptedException),
    typeof(ElementNotSelectableException),
    typeof(ElementNotInteractableException));
try
{
    Func(TestCaseInput, testCaseStep);
}

catch (WebDriverTimeoutException webDriverTimeoutException)
{                   
    testCaseStep.ErrorMessage = $@"""Exception Occoured in Method: 
        '{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}' with Exception: '{webDriverTimeoutException.StackTrace}'                      
        ""WebDriverTimeoutException.InnerException is::"" {webDriverTimeoutException.InnerException}                        
        ""Exception occured due to timeout""";
}
```

Is there any way to capture or listen to unhandled exceptions in MSTest in TestCleanUp. Is there any way to get the exceptions thrown from TestExplorer using some reflection or other mechanisms in c#

NOTE: I do not want to have some try/catch blocks for every method.

[image: Exception thrown for ElementNotInteractable]

I was able to handle every exception raised from selenium using the EventFiringWebDriver. This solves one part of my problem. But there are some exceptions raised from .net framework for example I'm expecting a dropdown to contain some values and select one of the value from dropdown Like 
IList accounts = driver.findElements(By.XPath("//a[id='accounts']"));
accounts.FirstOrDefault().Click(). If the accounts list doesn't have any webelements then it throws a "System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element" . I can put an if condition before clicking the element. if(accounts.Any()) but I cannot put such conditions around all such dropdowns.

I went through some links which are helpful in the cases of asp.net or .netcore to log firstexceptions or any exceptions but I couldn't find related links to MSTest unhandled exceptions. This link https://stackify.com/csharp-catch-all-exceptions/ has been useful for asp.net or .netcore
to log every exception:

Comment: Lets say you catch the exceptions through whatever magic means and get a list of them in CleanUp. What would be the expected outcome of a test that throws an exception of that kind?

Comment: Test should get failed and an exception should be recorded into the reports

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the folllowing. Extend the TestMethod and decorate with the new one.

```
public class SeleniumTestMethodAttribute : TestMethodAttribute
{
     public override TestResult[] Execute(ITestMethod testMethod)
     {
        try {
             base.Execute(testMethod);
        }
        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException webDriverTimeoutException)
        {                    
            testCaseStep.ErrorMessage = $@"""Exception Occoured in Method: 
                '{MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name}' with Exception: '{webDriverTimeoutException.StackTrace}'                      
                    ""WebDriverTimeoutException.InnerException is::"" {webDriverTimeoutException.InnerException}                        
                ""Exception occured due to timeout""";
        }
    }
}
```

And then decorate with

```
[SeleniumTestMethodAttribute]
public void TestMethodWithSelenium() {
}
```

Comment: what happens to the TestResult[] if an exception does occur? Does MSTest automatically set it to UnitTestOutcome.Failed?